# Change The Data Validation for Cell Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that I would like to save in 2 copies: One for current EMEA region and 2nd for APAC region. For this purpose I am trying to modify the data validation for one cell using the code below but the code stops and shows

> 1004 error.

The `APAC_Country` is the standard named region accessible in name manager. I have also tried to directly refer to the range instead of the named range but with similar result. What do I need to modify?

```
With Sheets("Selection").Range("F5")
    With .Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=APAC_Country"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Do you have a sheet named `Selection` ?

Comment: @Mikku Yes, I have

Comment: You code seems alright to me.

Comment: @Mikku Only if there is no data validation in `F5`. Run it twice to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is already a data validation in that cell you need to delete it before you add another one.

```
With Worksheets("Selection").Range("F5").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=APAC_Country"
End With
```

Comment: Yes, there was a different data validation range already assigned. It works now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

On top of Pᴇʜ's comment, there are two additional cases where you might receive `1004` error message:

1. **APAC_Country** doesn't exist (you already confirmed it does exist).
2. **APAC_Country** does exist, however, it is scoped to a different worksheet. Go to `Name Manager` and check the `Scope` of the range. If it is assigned to a different worksheet (different to "Selection"), then your VBA code will trigger `1004` error. The range needs to be assigned either to "Selection" worksheet or to the whole `Workbook`.

Comment: Thanks very much for help. It was caused by delete missing as suggested by Pᴇʜ.

Comment: For completeness I found one more case when it generates the very same error which is when the sheet is protected